# Tap callback on bar in BarChart in iOS-Charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have implemented a bar chart and I would like to move to a more specific view when tapping a specific bar - just as if I tapped a `UIButton`. Is this possible? I need to know which bar I tapped in order to fill my other view with correct data, but I can't seem to find any way to bind an action to a specific bar in a `BarChart`. I'm using `Swift`.

Comment: is BarChart from type of UIView?

Comment: @mariusLAN Yes, it is.

Comment: ok, than it's easy. Answer is coming ;)

Comment: @mariusLAN Thanks, but I think I found it. There is actually a callback for the BarChart, I just couldn't find the delegate to use it. I'll post an answer when I got it working.

Comment: otherwise check out pointInside

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the answer it was quite straight forward. Just implement the `ChartViewDelegate` where you have your `BarChartView` and simply implement the method `func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: ChartHighlight)` and you're all set.

Comment: Also, if you are using Charts in a `UICollectionView`, `UITableView`, or `UIScrollView` the chart might soak some of the `touch events` causing all kinds of havoc. You need to set parameters for your chart to avoid this. For instance I got `touch event` in my `BarChartView` when I scrolled my `UICollectionView` causing a crash since there was nothing to scroll to. The solution was to set `Chart.dragEnabled = false` since I only need tap and not scroll.

Comment: Thanks..!
Chart.dragEnabled = false
it was more helpful for us...!

Comment: Can you share the code? Am not sure where to call this function.

Comment: @deepakssn sorry, this was for a project for a client way back so I don't have access to the code anymore and even if I did I would not be allowed to share it.

Furthermore this was so long ago that I don't even remember what this was. I don't think I can help you, sorry :(

Comment: Thanks for the response @ClockWise. 
I figured it out. I did not have to write any code to call this delegate method. Adding  ChartViewDelegate  to the class calls the chartValueSelected when the chart is selected. I created my action inside this function.